# Securing Nodejs express API

Tags: node.js, express

I am making a very basic REST API using Express 4 (express.Router). How can I secure this API in a simple way?

I do not need to authenticate individual users so most of the strategies that I have found seem like overkill. I am just trying to moderately secure the API so I am hopefully the only one using it. Not sure what strategy I can use to pass something from the client to identify myself. Thanks!

I will be accessing this API from a web page as well as mobile client (with Ionic) and hosting the app on Google Clouds App Engine.

Comment: Check express **helmet** or **lusca** with kraken.

Comment: What are you accessing the API from?  From a web page?  From another server?  From a mobile client?  If you're going to use some sort of security credential to make sure that only you are using it, then we need to understand the client environment so we know what is appropriate.

Comment: @jfriend00 I am currently accessing from a web page, but will also be accessing from a mobile client (using Ionic). Also, if it makes a difference, I am planning to host the node app on Google Cloud App Engine. 
Thanks for the help.

Comment: @mrshickadance - If accessing from a web page, you cannot secure things.  No security credential in a web page can be kept secret.  Any web request you issue from a web page can be copied and used by anyone else.  The usual way of dealing with this is to require an authenticated user account before the web page can use the service and to have terms of service that prohibit misuse and then you monitor usage and suspend accounts that are abusing.  Also, clarifying answering questions people ask 13 hours later makes it hard to make progress here.

Comment: @jfriend00, got it. I know it will never be truly really secure. Just wondering if there were ways to make it at least partially secure, or add some hoops to jump through.

Comment: There are lots of ways to add hoops.  You have to target a specific client environment to get any useful answers to this question since each client environment has it's own unique circumstances.  A private client on a protected server can just use a secret password over https.  A browser client can't keep any secret.  What exactly are you trying to protect from?

Comment: Clients on the browser is what I am looking at now. I'm just trying to protect my API from being heavily used by anyone else. It's a simple wrapper for the Spotify Web Api since I have to do server-server auth with them. They have rate limits, so I don't want unnecessary traffic.

Comment: You can use [CORS](https://enable-cors.org) to protect your endpoint so it cannot be accessed from a different host.

Comment: @zGeek, thanks for the suggesting. Looking into that, have to see how that'd work with iOS and Android apps.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a header or a query string to authenticate. For example, setup a middleware on Express to check if the header `X-TOKEN` contains a string of your choice.

Here's a code which you can use to do that:

```
function checkAuthHeader (req, res, next) {
    let token = req.headers['X-TOKEN'];
    if (token && token == "RANDOM_GENERATED_STRING") {
        next();
    } else {
       res.status(403).end('Unauthorized.')
    }
}
```

Then you can use this function as a middleware like this (make sure you place it before declaring your routes):

```
app.use(checkAuthHeader)
```

You should be using environmental variables instead of a hard-coded string as well. I just used a hard coded one for demonstration.

Comment: Don't see how this is going to work for the wide variety of access clients the OP wants to use.  For example, putting a secret like this in a web page just hands the secret to everyone in the world.

Comment: Since OP said "I am hopefully the only one using it.", I thought it was for his personal use where it could be used for a single client.